# Access Vue instance's computed properties object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Vue components exposes `this.$data`. Is there any way to access computed properties in a similar fashion?

They are not exposed on `$data`, and there is no such thing as `this.$computed`

Comment: this.nameOfComputedProperty

Comment: @thanksd As the question implies, I'm asking for a collection of the computed properties, as opposed to explicitly selecting them

Comment: ah ok that wasn't clear to me

Comment: @thanksd Should have been more clear in the question, sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way to access an object with the computed properties of a Vue instance.

If you really want an object of computed property name and values for testing purposes you could define your own `$computed` property using the information in the `_computedWatchers` property. This might be finicky and I wouldn't use it in production code.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$computed', { 
  get() { 
    let computed = {};
    Object.keys(this._computedWatchers).forEach((key) => {
      computed[key] = this._computedWatchers[key].value;
    })
    return computed;
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      foo: 1,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    bar() {
      return this.foo * 2;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$computed)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">{{ bar }}</div>
```

Comment: this answer needs re-evaluation, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a way.

```
const app = Vue.createApp(yourVueModelObj);    
let appObject = await app.mount('#yourHtmlDomElement');
let value = appObject.$['ctx'].yourComputedProperty
```